# Why does the output of this code not appear on console?

Tags: java

```
public class Ejercicio2{
    //Declaración de las variables
    {
        int isco=22;
        int neymar=19;
        //Operaciones Condicionales
        if(isco>neymar)
            System.out.println("isco es mayor que neymar");
    }
}
```

I cannot make it work, it is a second class that I created for another exercise which is not shown on the console, while the first exercise is shown, not even showing error

Comment: You're missing a main method.

Comment: You can't have if-statements outside a method. If that's really the code you have, it will not compile and you will get a compiler error message.

Comment: You need to describe what behavior you are seeing and what you are expecting. This site tries not to answer homework questions directly, but give you the info you need to solve your own problems. Without describing that problem not many people will spend their time to help.

Comment: BTW, you might want to feel more comfortable on https://es.stackoverflow.com/ or https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: How the compiler understood your code: [The Initializer Block in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-26-the-initializer-block-in-java/).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a method called `main`

```
public class Ejercicio2
{
    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ... if statement goes here ...
    }
}
```

`main` is always the entry point to your program, that is - where the execution of your program starts. So unless that's been supplied for you, you need to create it to make your program run.

Further, any statements like loops or conditionals need to be inside a method.